# When archiving files which command will preserve all file attributes including ACLs and SElinux security context?

Tags: linux, archive

I think this should be tar command however I am still wondering if using gzip can be still valid option?
Any ideas?

THanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to include `--selinux` and `--acls`.  Check the [GNU tar documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Extended-File-Attributes.html#SEC70) for more details on what those entail.  Might want to also include `--xattrs` too.

Gzip is probably the most portable, but all recent versions also support bzip2 (`--bzip2` or `-j`) and xz (`--xz` or `-J`).  The documentation lists [all the options for compression](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/gzip.html#SEC135).